# How do I find arccos(-16.503)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help please? I have tried using my calculator and out of what I have already learned yet nothing is working.

I'm trying to calculate $$\arccos(-16.503)$$

Comment: $-16.503$ is outside the domain of $\arccos{x}$.

Comment: So, the problem seems to lie in an earlier step. How did you arrive at the expression $\arccos(-16.503)$?

Comment: @Oliver An entire function (of which cosine is one) takes every complex number as a value, with the exception of perhaps a single point. This is Picard's Little Theorem.

Comment: @Fly, the question is tagged algebra-precalculus. Unlikely that Picard's Theorem is in the syllabus.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True, but my comment was tagged for Oliver and I assume it has been on his syllabus.

Answer (score 1):

The complex cosine function is such that if $z=x+\mathrm{i}y$, for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$\cos z = \cos x \cosh y - \mathrm{i}\sin x \sinh y$$
If $\alpha = \arccos(-16.503)$ then $\cos \alpha = -16.503$. Can we find an $x+\mathrm{i}y$ such that
$$\cos x \cosh y - \mathrm{i}\sin x \sinh y = -16.503 + \mathrm{i}\,0$$
Since $-16.503$ has no imaginary part, we need $\sin x \sinh y = 0$. This happens when either $\sin x = 0$ or $\sinh y=0$. Notice that $\sin x = 0 \iff x = \pi n$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\sinh y = 0 \iff y = 0$. There are two choices: $z=x+\mathrm{i}\,0$ or $z=\pi n + \mathrm{i}y$.

If $z=x+\mathrm{i}\,0$ then $\cos z = \cos x$ and $-1 \le \cos x \le 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This means there is no solution. If $z=\pi n + \mathrm{i}y$ then $\cos z = \cos \pi n \cosh y =(-1)^n\cosh y$.

Notice that $\cosh y \ge 1$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and so we need $n$ to be odd in order to solve $(-1)^n\cosh y = -16.503$. Assuming that $n$ is odd, i.e. $z=(2k+1)\pi+\mathrm{i}y$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $\cosh y = 16.503$, i.e. $y=\operatorname{arccosh} 16.503$. The final result gives:
$$z = (2k+1)\pi + \mathrm{i}\operatorname{arccosh}16.503$$
If you prefer, you can express $\operatorname{arccosh}z$ as $\ln\left(z+\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}\right)$.